# Invalid Credentials error when uploading files to Google Drive via API

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I run a daily PHP program that uploads files to Google Drive via API.
It has been in operation since the beginning of April and is usually operating normally.

But I got an error only on May 17th(JST).
I got the following "Invalid Credentials" error.

```
Error Message: Google\Service\Exception: {
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This error is happening only on May 17th and not on any other days.
I'm uploading 25 files a day by same program and only 9 have errors.
The upload times are almost the same.

I wonder why the error occurred only in these 9 cases.

- The program is executed before 8:00 every morning, but there is no particular regularity in the error occurrence time.
- The token has not expired.
- There have been no reports of problems with Google Drive or the Drive API itself.
- Even on the server running cron, there were no failures on that day.

What could be the cause?
Please advise on how to resolve.

Best regards.

Comment: Could it be possible that a file name, with special characters or space or else throws an error and be blocked?

Comment: May have a been a temporary glitch somewhere considering it has worked the days after the 17th. You could code it so it retries after a few minutes of a failure

Comment: It could be helpful to see the code which tries to connect.

Comment: Thank you for replies. The file name is like this: 012345_AMS_SP_20230517.csv. It doesn't have special characters or space. I'll consider implementing retries as you say.